# JasperReports: Custom Arabic Font Doesn't appear

Tags: java, fonts, jasper-reports, arabic

I'm trying a sample example of calling Jasper report from Java SE (GUI application)

The problem was in the Arabic character doesn't displayed, however I use the method #1 of install the custom font

JRxml:

```xml
<staticText>
        <reportElement x="0" y="120" width="555" height="42"/>
        <textElement textAlignment="Center">
            <font fontName="Arial" pdfFontName="ARIAL.TTF" size="22″ isPdfEmbedded ="true" pdfEncoding ="Identity-H"/>
        </textElement>
        <text><![CDATA[DejaVu Serif]]></text>
</staticText>
```

But unfortunately find doesn't displayed

Steps which I follow:

1. Install custom font Arial from windows
2. Export Arial.jar
3. Add Arial.jar to my classpath
4. change font name, pdf font name in JRxml
5. generate the report

*Note I try to change pdfFontName attribute to "Arial" with no good news

Environment Setup

- iReport-4.5.0
- JDK 1.6
- Windows 7 64bit

Answer (score -1):

After working a lot here it is :

- Know that i tested it on iReport 3.0 only .
- As Pdf makes arabic not being displayed or appearing as ??? .

[First add the font arial.ttf by copying it from windows folder to fonts folder in ireport installation directory http://www.pixentral.com/pics/1bWWWnlE3mgVQHNG8BGaQs4SVn41.png](http://www.pixentral.com/pics/1bWWWnlE3mgVQHNG8BGaQs4SVn41.png)

[Add the folder with that font to font class path of ireport http://www.pixentral.com/pics/1MYNPGcL2SaTY07rcEMO8Z1VF918I0.png](http://www.pixentral.com/pics/1MYNPGcL2SaTY07rcEMO8Z1VF918I0.png)

[Going to fontclass path http://www.pixentral.com/pics/1YCoyHF3YlrXTMjUr3OegqyVVUqhC91.png](http://www.pixentral.com/pics/1YCoyHF3YlrXTMjUr3OegqyVVUqhC91.png)

[The main step here as follow at element properties change the font with pdf to arial.ttf that you just added and check the pdf embeded encoding on, and finally choose Identity-H (Unicode with horizontal writing) option http://www.pixentral.com/pics/1YZfiW9r0P4OlFRKftmQ1liiMZF31.png](http://www.pixentral.com/pics/1YZfiW9r0P4OlFRKftmQ1liiMZF31.png)

Comment: some time the pics take a day so i will wait if did not work i will add it as link ref image because it need image server hosting

Comment: The problem solved with me after change font name to  make sure that jasper lookup on my font name it like your name "salem"

Then add font into project and make font name in jasperxmpl "salem"
But make sure that it PDFencoding ="Identity-H" like below

<font fontName="salem" size="18" isBold="true" pdfEncoding="Identity-H"/>

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. But, unfortunately none picture is accessible.